# BeakerX: Enabling/Disabling?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

How can `beakerx` be enabled for only specific `jupyter` notebooks?

Can `beakerx` be enable/disabled from within a notebook?

After `python3 -m pip install -UI beakerx` and then `beakerx install`, `beakerx` seems to be enabled for all `jupyter` notebooks, all the time.

Comment: Another _**Tumbleweed**_ winner!